# Open-source business event logger/statistics tool which can integrate easily with Spring applications

Tags: open-source, java, logs, log-analysis, statistics

I am looking for a tool to help me monitor and generate statistics on events happening in business applications.

A simple example of this would be "A person does a lookup in a search bar" or "A client purchased product X". So I can use this information to generate information to give a better overview on the usage of the system, rather than the processor time being utilized.

The business applications can have a dependency on a library to do this, and do calls to an external application to do the logging (preferably using Spring Integration).

I have been unable to find a system which does this, but I don't want to have to resort to building it myself just yet.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Fluentd

Fluentd is an open source data collector for unified logging layer.
Fluentd allows you to unify data collection and consumption for a better use and understanding of data.

Further Information could be found here: http://www.fluentd.org/

### 2. Drools

Drools is a Business Rules Management System (BRMS) solution. It provides a core Business Rules Engine (BRE), a web authoring and rules management application (Drools Workbench) and an Eclipse IDE plugin for core development.

Further Information could be found here: http://www.drools.org/

Comment: I've looked at both, and I don't really see how I can integrate them with my applications in the way I described it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to monitor is 2 different types of data.

a) Business transaction Monitoring : Try AppDynamics or New Relic that will work well for these requirements where you want to understand the time, resource consumption of your business apps. If you want of integrate this with Spring apps, try Spring Insight :http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/2.0/devedition/htmlsingle/devedition.html

(or)Commercial : 
https://www.vmware.com/products/vrealize-hyperic/

b) Web Analytic Product or E-commerce tracking , there's a lot of products try something like Google Analytics
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce